# String variable not updating c++

Tags: c++

I have a program that basically opens a .sql database file and returns the table names into a string vector. This string vector is stored as `tableNames` and contains the tables within a given database file. For some reason that I cannot understand, the `tableName` parameter in the `sqlCreateTemp` string is not updated, but the varible `tableName` is.

```c++
void fileWrite()
{
    string tableName;
    string sqlCreateTemp = "CREATE TABLE tempLog AS SELECT * FROM " + tableName + "; UPDATE tempLog SET TIMESTAMP1=strftime('%s', datetime(timestamp1, 'localtime')) + strftime('%f', timestamp1) - strftime('%S', timestamp1);";


    int rc = -1;
    vector<string> tableNames = getTableNames();

    for(int i = 0; i < tableNames.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "TABLENAMES = " << tableNames[i] << endl;
        tableName = tableNames[i] ;
        cout << "tableName = " tableName << endl;
        cout << "SQL = " << sqlCreateTemp << endl;
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
TABLENAMES = testTableABC
tableName = testTableABC
SQL = CREATE TABLE tempLog AS SELECT * FROM ; UPDATE tempLog SET TIMESTAMP1=strftime('%s', datetime(timestamp1, 'localtime')) + strftime('%f', timestamp1) - strftime('%S', timestamp1);
```

Comment: `tableName` is not a parameter to `sqlCreateTemp`. When one changes, the other doesn't change automatically. You have to recreate the string, when the `tableName` changes.

Comment: Why should `sqlCreateTemp` have a change in value? You never change it after you create it

Comment: @cigien I would have thought that becuase I was updating the `tableName` variable and then outputting `sqlCreateTemp` that the `tableName` parameter would update. I guess not. It works when I constantly update the string anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer executes your code one statement at a time, in a logical manner.

```
string tableName;
```

This creates a new `std::string`. It is an empty string.

```
string sqlCreateTemp = "CREATE TABLE tempLog AS SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ...
```

This creates another `std::string`, whose contents includes `tableName`. Which is empty, as we've just observed, so this part of `sqlCreateTemp`'s contents is empty.

Code that executes later then sets new values of `tableName`:

```
tableName = tableNames[i] ;
```

That's fine, but this does not automatically change the contents of `sqlCreateName`. C++ does not work this way. Its value was set at the beginning of this function, and is never changed again. At the time that it was set, `tableName` was an empty string, and that's that.

If you want to create a new value of `sqlCreateTemp` each time `tableName` changes, you have to write the code to do it. The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming says, after all: your computer always does exactly, and precisely, what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. If you want your computer to change the value of `sqlCreateTemp`, each time `tableName`'s value changes, you must tell your computer to do that, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need update the `sqlCreateTemp` after you update `tableName` variable, like this:

```
...

for(int i = 0; i < tableNames.size(); i++)
{
    cout << "TABLENAMES = " << tableNames[i] << endl;
    tableName = tableNames[i] ;
    sqlCreateTemp = "CREATE TABLE tempLog AS SELECT * FROM " + tableName + "; UPDATE tempLog SET TIMESTAMP1=strftime('%s', datetime(timestamp1, 'localtime')) + strftime('%f', timestamp1) - strftime('%S', timestamp1);";
    cout << "tableName = " tableName << endl;
    cout << "SQL = " << sqlCreateTemp << endl;
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way so that your tableName variable gets updated:

```
void fileWrite()
{
    string tableName;
    string sqlCreateTemp_part1 = "CREATE TABLE tempLog AS SELECT * FROM ";
    string sqlCreateTemp_part2 = "; UPDATE tempLog SET TIMESTAMP1=strftime('%s', datetime(timestamp1, 'localtime')) + strftime('%f', timestamp1) - strftime('%S', timestamp1);";

    string sqlCreateTemp;

    int rc = -1;
    vector<string> tableNames = getTableNames();

    for(int i = 0; i < tableNames.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "TABLENAMES = " << tableNames[i] << endl;
        tableName = tableNames[i] ;
        cout << "tableName = " tableName << endl;
        sqlCreateTemp = sqlCreateTemp_part1 + tableName + sqlCreateTemp_part2;
        cout << "SQL = " << sqlCreateTemp + << endl;
    }
}
```